# LWC, Error "document.write is not a function" using third party JS

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, lightning-experience

I'm trying to integrate simple Google Books preview button, from a LWC in an experience B2B site. If the book preview is available, this function writes out a "Google Preview" button that simply links off to a preview page for the book.
I'm importing the js as a static resource, and making the call inside of a connectedCallback:

```
connectedCallback() {
        Promise.all([loadScript(this, gbPreview)])
            .then(() => {
                console.log('script is loaded')
                GBS_insertPreviewButtonLink('ISBN:0738531367');            
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log('error:', error);
            });
```

This call seems to work, but for some reason, the script cannot run:

```
script is loaded
b2bGooglePreview.js:1 error: TypeError: document.write is not a function
    at jH (GoogleBookPreview:656:220)
    at fH (GoogleBookPreview:654:674)
    at Proxy.eval (GoogleBookPreview:654:403)
    at eval (b2bGooglePreview.js:1:810)
```

I tried with light DOM, but it doesn't work.
If anyone can point me in the right direction, I would be very much appreciated,
thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use `document.write`, you need to control the top-level HTML, as this function can only be called while the HTML is being parsed into the DOM through a synchronous script. After the `DOMContentLoaded` event occurs, no further modifications to the DOM are allowed via `document.write`.

This means that you would need to use an inline synchronous script to call this correctly, and that's not allowed in LWC. Such a library is, unfortunately, not compatible with LWC or most other Web Component frameworks, unless you have full control over the top-level HTML that initially loads the runtime.

For example, you could do this in LWC OSS, because you control the loading of the runtime. For Salesforce-hosted features (including the UI, Digital Experiences, etc), there's no possible way to load this.

In summary, you can't load this library this way. You'll need to find an alternative library or another solution, such as patching the library to render elements dynamically, then using `lwc:dom="manual"` for a container to attach this render to.

Answer (score 2):

To add to @sfdcfox's comment and in case it helps anyone in the future, I ended up moving the request to an Apex class and returning the url of the response to the lwc component